# How to change position of ttk.Treeview?

Tags: tkinter, treeview, ttk

How to move the second Treeview widget somewhere at the middle of the window to have the widgets uniformly distributed ?
I tried grid and place but doesn't work cause pack method is already used...

[image]

Comment: `pack` has many options, have you experimented with them? Also, "somewhere at the middle" and "uniformly distributed" are somewhat vague phrases. If you want each treeview to take up an equal amount of space, that's pretty easy. Using `pack` to put a widget "somewhere at the middle" can be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you probably want a splitter so they can be resized by the user.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
root = tk.Tk()
pw = ttk.Panedwindow(root)
a = ttk.Treeview(pw)
b = ttk.Treeview(pw)
pw.add(a)
pw.add(b)
pw.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

If you didn't want to do that then use either grid *or* pack. Each widget that can contain children has to choose a single geometry management strategy to handle the placement of the contained widgets. All the contained widgets must use the same geometry management. So to put the two treeview widgets into a frame so that they take up equal space we can demo using frames and the grid geometry manager. The grid manage takes a weight option to assign free space widgets according to their weight value. If they have the same weight, they get the same amount of space.

```
t = tk.Toplevel(root)
f1 = tk.Frame(t, background="red")
f2  = tk.Frame(t, background="green")
f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
f2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')
t.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # configure column 0 to use all space
t.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # configure rows 0 and 1 to share space evenly
t.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

The same can be done using pack.

```
f1.grid_forget()
f2.grid_forget()
f1.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
f2.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

In general grid is more flexible and worth learning to use.